# shinydashboardPlus/dashboardUser. Collapse User box

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I adapted the code from [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/shinydashboardPlus/man/dashboardUser.html).
This is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(userOutput("user")),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(uiOutput("body")),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$user <- renderUser({
      dashboardUser(
        name = "Divad Nojnarg", 
        image = "https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg", 
        title = "shinydashboardPlus",
        subtitle = "Author", 
        footer = p("The footer", class = "text-center"),
        fluidRow(
          actionButton("btn1","Click")
        )
      )
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$btn1, {  #Not triggering
      output$body <- renderUI({print("Clicked")})
    })      
  }
)
```

What I want is the user box (what is in red) **not** to remain active (I mean, to make it to disappear) when I click on the button.

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround to do this is to use `shinyjs::hide()` and `shinyjs::show()`. Targeting the action button inside the user is easy. The tricky part is to get the dashboard user to show up again when the dropdown menu is clicked. For this we can rewrite the `dashboardUser()` function and add an action link with id instead of the "normal" link. See comments in code:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)

dashboardUser

myDashboardUser <- function (..., name = NULL, image = NULL, title = NULL, subtitle = NULL, 
                             footer = NULL) 
{
  if (!is.null(title)) {
    line_1 <- paste0(name, " - ", title)
  }
  else {
    line_1 <- name
  }
  if (!is.null(subtitle)) {
    user_text <- shiny::tags$p(line_1, shiny::tags$small(subtitle))
    user_header_height <- NULL
  }
  else {
    user_text <- shiny::tags$p(line_1)
    user_header_height <- shiny::tags$script(
      shiny::HTML("$(\".user-header\").css(\"height\", \"145px\")")
    )
  }
  userTag <- shiny::tagList(
    shiny::tags$head(
      shiny::tags$script("$(function() {\n
                           $('.dashboard-user').on('click', function(e){\n
                           e.stopPropagation();\n
                           });\n
                           });\n
                           ")),
    # we need to add an id and the class `action-button` to this link
    shiny::tags$a(id = "user_dropdown",
                  href = "#",
                  class = "dropdown-toggle action-button",
                  `data-toggle` = "dropdown",
                  shiny::tags$img(src = image,
                                  class = "user-image",
                                  alt = "User Image"),
                  shiny::tags$span(class = "hidden-xs",
                                   name)
    ),
    shiny::tags$ul(class = "dropdown-menu dashboard-user", 
                   shiny::tags$li(class = "user-header",
                                  if (!is.null(user_header_height)) user_header_height,
                                  shiny::tags$img(src = image, 
                                                  class = "img-circle",
                                                  alt = "User Image"),
                                  user_text), 
                   if (length(list(...)) > 0) 
                     shiny::tags$li(class = "user-body", ...),
                   if (!is.null(footer)) 
                     shiny::tags$li(class = "user-footer", footer)
    )
  )
  userTag
}
}

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(userOutput("user")),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      # make ShinyJs available
      useShinyjs(),
      uiOutput("body")
    ),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    output$user <- renderUser({
      myDashboardUser(
        name = "Divad Nojnarg", 
        image = "https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg", 
        title = "shinydashboardPlus",
        subtitle = "Author", 
        footer = p("The footer", class = "text-center"),
        fluidRow(
          actionButton("btn1","Click")
        )
      )
    })
    
    # use shinyjs::hide on button and also remove class open from user menue
    observeEvent(input$btn1, { 
      hide(selector = ".dropdown-menu.dashboard-user")
      removeClass(id = "user", class = "open")
    })      
    
    # use shinyjs::show on new link
    observeEvent(input$user_dropdown, { 
      show(selector = ".dropdown-menu.dashboard-user")
    })      
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. When I open the app, the user box is already open, and when the "btn1" is clicked, the user box disappear (what is what Im looking for), but the shadow of selection on "tag$a" (id="user_dropdown") does not disappear.

Comment: I now separated `hide()` and `show()` which allows us to remove the clicked box shadow from the link. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I realized that by clicking anywhere, the user box disappear, I have just used a piece of javascript code to simulate clicking over "body" element:

```
      jscode<-
        'var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  var cb = document.getElementById("body"); 
  var simulateClick = cb.dispatchEvent(evt);'
```

My final version:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(userOutput("user")),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(useShinyjs(), uiOutput("body")),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$user <- renderUser({
      dashboardUser(
        name = "Divad Nojnarg", 
        image = "https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg", 
        title = "shinydashboardPlus",
        subtitle = "Author", 
        footer = p("The footer", class = "text-center"),
        fluidRow(
          actionButton("btn1","Click")
        )
      )
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$btn1, {  #Not triggering
      output$body <- renderUI({print("Clicked")})
      jscode<-
        'var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  var cb = document.getElementById("body"); 
  var simulateClick = cb.dispatchEvent(evt)';
      
      runjs(jscode)
      
    })      
  }
)
```